# How can I update input field when the model hasn't technically changed but input field value has in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an input field that is referencing a model, there is restrictions on this input field (no special characters) so I have created a custom pipe to strip invalid characters. This is working for the most part. However, if I enter an invalid character the invalid character will stay there until I enter a valid value. I know why this is happening, because the value being returned from the custom pipe is the same as the model, therefore the ngModelChange event isn't detecting a change and not updating the input field.

How do I force the input field to re-render?

I'm pretty new to angular, and I'm not sure the best way to handle this. I want to make sure I understand what the problem actually is.

I've tried to search for this issue, however the solutions that I've found point to using Change Detection, but I don't think will help with this problem because there's technically not a change. I was also thinking of adding a *ngIf method to compare the input field value to the method but this seems a little hacky and doesn't really help me understand the actual problem

I've also tried implementing this using an input pattern, but had difficulty which I think is because we're using Ionic as well, and they do it differently to Angular.

I'm using Angular 5 with Ionic 4.

user.html:

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="username" [ngModel]="username | transformUsername" (ngModelChange)="username=$event"></ion-input>
```

user.ts:

```
@Pipe({
    name:'transformUsername'
})
export class TransformUsername implements PipeTransform{
    transform(username:any):any{
      return username.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

I'd like this to operate in a way that characters that don't match the regex in the pipe function just don't appear at all.

Comment: First of all, if you don't want to render anything, why is it replaced with `.`? Secondly, do you really need a pipe for this task? Is it used on other places?

Comment: Apologies - the . was added when I was testing a theory, I forgot to remove it before I pasted the snippet here. That should be an empty string, I’ll update it. And also, no - it doesn’t have to be a pipe, I’m open to any method that works, it’s just that the pipe got me the closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that works well for what we're after using Directives, so I thought I'd post my solution in case anyone else comes across a similar problem.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[usernameValidator]'
})

export class UsernameDirective{
  usernameRegex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/g;
  inputElement: HTMLElement;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.key.match(this.usernameRegex) !== null) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```